# How to parse the construction "Чьи это были деньги?"

Tags: грамматика

> Чьи **это** были деньги?
>
> {instead of}: Чьи **эти** были деньги?

What I'm struggling to wrap my head around is why you need to use the singular "это" with all the other plural words here.

Should I interpret the sentence structure this way:

> Чьи деньги были это?
>
> {or}: Это были чьи деньги?

---

To complicate matters further, both "эти" and "это" seem to work in the present tense:

> Чьи **эти** деньги?
>
> Чьи **это** деньги?

Comment: I believe the reason is that "деньги" here is more "uncountable" than "plural" by the usage tradition. The referred object is some vague "pile of money" or "sump of money" rather that specific "three money and a half". Though etymologically "деньги" is plural form of "деньга" :-D This would not matter much though. If to use "чьи это монеты?" or "...купюры?" or "...банкноты?" I would still use "это" because the whole group of objects is being meant rather than every coin in that group particularly.

Answer (score 5):

Чьи **это** были деньги? - Accent on WHO own this money.

Чьи были **эти** деньги? - Accent on MONEY type or source of this MONEY.

**For example:**

I brought some money to You. 1000 RUR + 100 USD.

**You ask:** *Чьи **это** деньги?*

**Answer:** Это всё наши с другом деньги.

**You ask:** *Чьи **эти** деньги?* (and point on 100 USD)

**Answer:** Эти деньги - моего друга. Он добавил их к моим 1000 рублям (RUR).

Comment: the phrase "Чьи *эти* деньги? (and point on 100 USD)" is looking at least plausible, though I wouldn't say it, and would use instead, "Чьи *это* деньги?", even while pointing a finger at the money. In the last line you should have used the dash to indicate the pause, "Эти деньги — моего друга". Without the pause the last line "**Эти** деньги моего друга" is looking as something 99% of the native speakers would never say.

Comment: Эти деньги - моего друга. Sure.

Comment: Эти деньги can be used when you have a choice, эти и те or when it means "this very money", so the usage is limited. Otherwise you say это either pointing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Another example of semantic difference between **это** and **эти**

> -Чьи это деньги? - Это мои деньги <sup>*possession*</sup>
>   -Чьи эти деньги? - Это американские деньги <sup>*source*</sup>

Based on DimXenon's example the *source* of money (implied with **эти**) means that someone furnished it, but whether it belongs to that person or not is beside the point.

For the sake of distinction maybe it's useful to treat ***Чьи ЭТО деньги?*** as ***Whose money is IT?*** while treating ***Чьи ЭТИ деньги?*** as ***Whose is THIS money?/Whose money is THIS?***

Comment: Nothing can be said against чьи это деньги?--это американские деньги.

Comment: possession/source explanation seems stretched, but IT/THIS distinction looks very good.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a choice, you can use **это**. Эти is more rarely used.
It also depends on the structure. If it is the subject, unchanged dummy "it", you say это, no matter what the tense is.

> Это были мои деньги. Это были российские купюры. Чьи это были деньги? Чьи это были купюры? Это мои деньги. Чьи это деньги?. Это российские купюры. Чьи это купюры?

But in the following examples эти is a determiner, in Russian указательное местоимение, этот, эта,это(for neuter gender),эти (for plural )

> Эти купюры американские, а те российские. Где‐то я уже видел эти книги. Чьи эти деньги?(this very money)